# Session expire DateTime is the same for all logged in users, how to prevent that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, global-asax

Session expire DateTime is the same for all logged in users, so when one user session expire, it seems to be expiring for all users because it records the same session expire datetime in the database. 
I am using InProc mode and the session expire date time is very important meaning I need to save it to the database..

I am using the Session_End function and save the DateTime.Now to a SQL server database from inside the Session_End function.

Comment: I think this text would not be sufficient to find out the answer.  You will have to provide minimal example from where anyone can repro the issue.

Comment: apppool recycle ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will not session expire, it is IIS restarted on the given time, so all users have same date time.